# Show detail data in RDLC report

Tags: winforms, rdlc

How can create a report that shows the master and detail rows in the same report?

I am working on trying to prepare statement for customers of their invoices and credits.

The structure is:

```
Customer

Invoice

Credit

Credit Detail

Payment

Payment Detail
```

The scenario for a customer:

A customer can have multiple Invoices,
Each Invoice can have multiple credits issued against a particular invoice.
Each Invoice can have multiple payments.

The statement should produce each outstanding invoice and list any payments or credits towards the invoice grouped under them.

There may be situations that the customer can have credits issued against no invoice. This also needs to be displayed without any invoice.

I need some advise on how this can be done using Winforms Report using RDLC.

Comment: I was able to use grouping by using additional tables that consolidates data for invoice.

Answer (score 0):

I created statementdata and statementdetail table that is preprocessed consolidating all invoices with their credit and payment amounts along with credits that were not issued to invoice instead to the customer (special credit). StatementDetail table will have the details of the credits and payments. Once we have this it becomes a master detail scenario. This made me easily show a statement with the following structure.

Customer Name and Address - Header

invoice 1 - Detail Section
  Details for Invoice 1 payment  - Sub Grouping
  Details for Invoice 1 credits  - Sub Grouping
invoice 2
  Details for Invoice 2 payment
  Details for Invoice 2 credits

etc.,

Thanks